# This war of mine will not load (linux)

Tags: steam, linux, ubuntu, this-war-of-mine

I am attempting to play This War Of Mine through steam on Ubuntu 15.04. However, once I launch the game, it makes it to the loading screen and will not go any farther. I am not getting any useful information from running it through the terminal.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you make sure your machine meets the minimal requirements? Does the game run on your graphics card? Do you have the right driver? Did you check the official issues listings? And so on.